# iPhone sdk for OSX 10.4

Tags: iphone, macos, sdk

On the apple website I can only see offered the iPhone sdk4 which indicates it will only operate on OSX10.6/Snow Leopard. Is this the case? And if so, where can I get the previous sdks so that I can work on my computer with OSX10.4?

Comment: Snow Leopard is only $29. Get it. Why do you expect any company to make current software that targets an OS that is 2 versions out of date and 5+ years old?

Comment: For example... if its not your computer... but yes I agree, I will persuade them to get it.

And actually you are wrong. I DO expect a certain level of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Well Apple unfortunately doesn't follow your (and my) expectation. They love doing away with backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yep.. latest version of sdk requires Snow Leopard.  I guess it's a good excuse to get the latest version.  :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a version of the iPhone SDK which works with Tiger. You also need an Intel Macintosh. You can still dowload the old (mac) SDK but it won't allow you to develop for iPhone, only Mac.